# Can't stop my custom windows service via gitlab-runner

Tags: gitlab, windows-services, gitlab-ci-runner, sc.exe

This is my first question on stackoverflow. Hope your eyes won't be bleeding too much from my English.
Long story short: I can't stop my custom windows service via gitlab-runner.

What I'm trying to achieve during gitlab CI\CD is:

- send a signal to my service to stop doing his job
- periodically check this service status to determine whether it is stopped or not

So, I've install shell gitlab-runner locally for ease and gitlab server sees my local runner.
My windows service has name in the following format: "**My.Service.Name**".

**gitlab-ci.yml** contains job <**my_job_name**> with following command inside script section `sc.exe queryex My.Service.Name` (trying to get service status).

Command execution gives me error `[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service`.
Basically, `sc.exe stop My.Service.Name` also failed with error `[SC] OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service`.

My service was created this way: `sc create My.Service.Name binPath= "path\to\exe\My.Service.Name.exe -service" DisplayName= My.Service.Name start= delayed-auto depend= MSMQ`.
[Local query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dLlj.png) of `sc.exe queryex My.Service.Name` call.

I was already checked this:

- my service exists and has same service and display names in services.msc (**My.Service.Name**)
- service name didn't contain any spaces (in case of missing quotes)
- simple command `sc.exe queryex` (via gitlab-runner) gives me not all services, that I can see in services.msc locally
- alternative command also not giving me all services from services.msc `Get-Service -ComputerName .` (via gitlab-runner)
- same commands executed locally gives me desired result via both sc.exe `sc.exe queryex My.Service.Name` and
  Get-Service in PowerShell `Get-Service | where {$_.name -like "*My.Service.Name*"} or Get-Service -ComputerName .`
- both services **gitlab-runner** and **My.Service.Name** are running with my local administrator account
- local run `gitlab-runner.exe exec shell my_job_name` gives me desired result also, so I can query service information and even stop service
- based on similar questions, I also checked that windows RPC services are enabled and currently running

So, why some services, including my service, are not listed in results of sc.exe and Get-Service (via gitlab-runner)? I suspect some permission issues here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally get what is wrong - I messed up with gitlab-ci.yml job tags and in fact, another gitlab-runner processed incoming build. Now it's working as expected.